# Parse a string inside a string in NearleyJS

Tags: javascript, parsing

Hi I am naive in CFG and I am trying to write a grammar for my expression but I am facing an issue while parsing a string inside the input value in nearley.

Below is my expression

```
"(I have a person: where "1+1=2")"
```

here is my grammar:

```
main -> statement {% id %}
statement -> "(" constline optional:? ")" 

constline -> "I have a person" {% id %}
optional -> ":where" _ "\"" whereclause "\"" _ {%d=>d[2]%}
whereclause -> _ expression _ compare _ expression {%d=> d[0]+d[1]+d[3]%}
expression -> numbers "+" numbers {% d=>d[0]+d[1]+d[2]%}
           | numbers "-" numbers  {% d=>d[0]+d[1]+d[2]%}
numbers -> digit
        | digit numbers {% d=> d[0]+d[1]%}
digit -> [0-9]
_ -> [\t]:*
```

now while parsing I am getting the below error:
:where "1+1=2")

```
Unexpected "\"". Instead, I was expecting to see one of the following:
A character matching /[0-9]/ based on:
   digit -> /[0-9]/
   numbers-> digit
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar is missing regular expressions for the lexer to work, so it does not understand most part of the grammar. Also you were missing out the compare closure, which I believe would mean '=' in our case. I think this should do it.

```js
@{%
const moo = require('moo');
let lexer = moo .compile({
    //string: /"(?:\\["bfnrt\/\\]|\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4}|[^"\\])*"/,
    numbers: /[0-9]+/,
    '"': '"',
    'I have a person': 'I have a person',
    '(': '(',
    ')': ')',
    ':': ':',
    '+': '+',
    '=': '=',
    '=': '=',
    ws: /[ \t]/,
    'where': 'where',
    
});
console.clear();

%}

@lexer lexer

main -> "\"" statement "\"" {% d => d[1] %}
statement -> "(" constline optional:? ")" 

constline -> "I have a person" {% id %}
optional -> ":" _ "where" _ expressionString _ {%d=>d[3]%}
whereclause -> _ expressionString _ compare _ expressionString {%d=> d[0]+d[1]+d[3]%}
expressionString -> "\"" expression "\"" {% d => d[1] %}
expression -> numbers "+" numbers "=" numbers {% d=>d[0]+d[1]+d[2]%}
           | numbers "-" numbers "=" numbers {% d=>d[0]+d[1]+d[2]%}
numbers -> digit {% id %}
        | digit numbers {% d=> d[0]+d[1]%}
digit -> [0-9]
_ -> [ \t]:*
```

Let me know if this work for you.